# Is it possible to dynamically trigger calling of the @PostLoad method only on demand

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Env: JBoss Seam, JPA, Hibernate

We use the @PostLoad annotation to dynamically initialize some of the transient variables in our @Entity (sometimes this involves looking up the parent entity to initialize status - which is a costly operation).

But under certain circumstances, we don't want this @PostLoad to get triggered, since we will not rely on the transient variables.

Is there a way to control the data dynamically post load.

One way to solve this issue, is to call this method only on demand (i.e. by removing the @PostLoad annotation and manually calling this method), but this is also error prone.

Are there any other ways to resolve this issue.

Comment: I think you have to tell us how do you expect Hibernate to know when to trigger postLoad and when not to? Base on the data of the entity? If what you want is do something like: session.pleaseTriggerPostLoad(Foo.class) before you read the data, then it is nothing differ from calling the method explicitly on demand.

Comment: It would be helpful to be able to send such a flag to JPA queries, since these types of state-updaters are expensive when run on large collections, and in eager-fetch situations. I've got a similar problem with a collection of accounts from salesforce data. Going to try a custom query to just get an ID list to build and then load objects with an overloaded constructor, setting a noExpiry flag that prevents the update.

Answer (score 1):

> But under certain circumstances, we don't want this @PostLoad to get triggered, since we will not rely on the transient variables.

Create two entities, one with the `@PostLoad` and the transient fields, and one "lighter" without.

Comment: do you think that this is possible? since there can be only a single @Entity class for a particular table and if @PostLoad is declared it will run it. Not sure if we can have 2 different entity classes. Kindly clarify

Comment: @Samuel Hmm... Who said *there can be only a single @Entity class for a particular table*? You CAN have several entities mapped on a same table. Now, I'm not saying this is ideal but in your case, this could be a solution.

Comment: I agree that this could be a possible workaround, but it would involve additional classes and possibly higher code maintenance

Comment: @Samuel: Actually, having several entities mapped on a same table was a common practice with Hibernate 2, when you couldn't use projections (so people were using a "light entity" with less attributes/associations for search screens and a "fat version" for detail screens). But you're right, this introduces extra maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't dealt with this in java but came across similar thing in kotlin + maven + spring project.

**Understanding how @PostLoad works?**

`@PostLoad` is called after fetching data using entity manager methods `find()` or `refresh()` operations is triggered to the database.

**Scenario when it fails to trigger @PostLoad :**

Suppose, a `parent` entity had this `@transient variable` which is initialised using a `@PostLoad` method. And also, you had a child entity which had mapping to this parent entity.

When you retrieve a `child` the find will load and persistence context is generated. Down the line when you tried to access parent content then another find is triggered. But this won't trigger the `@PostLoad` method of `parent` because the operation is triggered from the existing context.

Which would generally throw the uninitialized errors.

**Solution**

In the above scenario, I don't really need multiple entities. As I knew this behaviour. I would create an entity class method for `parent` to dynamically load the contents for the respective transient variable or even set some defaults for a special scenario. And trigger or manage this method in the converter methods or where-ever the use case is.